# List Files From Directory Handle and Search

Tags: php, list, file, directory

sorry before, my english not so well,,but hope you understand about my problem.

Well, i have a page that listing files from a directory, so far to show the files and to let user download it, the script work fine.

but the problem is, the table shows 2 empty columns and i don't know where they came from.

i try to cut all the files, and still there are 2 empty columns showed.

here's the script

- Handling files from directory -

  ```
      <table>
              <?php
                  $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('laporan/LaporanBulanan');
                  //$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

                  foreach ($dir_iterator as $file) {
                      ?>
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                  <?php               
                                      if ($file->isFile()) {
                                          echo substr($file->getFilename(), 0);
                                      }
                                  ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <?php               
                                      if ($file->isFile()) {
                                          echo $file->getSize()/1024 . ' KB';
                                      }
                                  ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <?php               
                                      if ($file->isFile()) {
                                          echo date('d-m-Y', $file->getMTime());
                                      }
                                  ?>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <a href="laporan/LaporanBulanan/<?php if ($file->isFile()) { echo substr($file->getFilename(), 0);}?>" style="height:30px">LIHAT</a>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                      <?php
                  }       

              ?>
      </table>
      <div>
          <div>
              <form id="fCariLap" method="post">
                  <input name="cariLap" style="width:300px;height:30px"></input>
                  <a id="bCariLap" href="javascript:void(0)" style="height:30px">Cari</a>
              </form>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('#bCariLap').on('click', function(){
                          $('#fCariLap').submit();
                      });
                  });
              </script>
          </div>
      </div>
  <?php
  ```

would you like to help me please..

and i also want to know, how to create a search form for the files listed ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
foreach ($dir_iterator as $file) {
    if (!$file->isFile()) continue; // skip, if it is not a file
```

Did I get you right?

Comment: thank you so much Oleg, it works...

and can we make search form to find the file ??